# How to use awk in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write the below awk in python

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next}!(NR%2){a=$0; next} {printf "%s %s%s%s", $1,a,FS,ORS}' FS=';' file
```

I tried using

```
os.system(' awk "FNR==1{print;next}!(NR%2){a=$0; next} {printf "%s %s%s%s", $1,a,FS,ORS}" FS=';' file ')
```

But I am getting syntax error.

Comment: The syntax error likely detailed the issue -- and if not, Stackoverflow Python formatting did. Notice the usage of `'` between `os.system('` and `'FNR`. You are closing the `'`. Instead, you need to make sure that inside the single quotes you _only_ use double quotes, or vice-versa.

Comment: Can you correct the code . So it will be better to understand

Comment: Posted below to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```py
os.system('awk "FNR==1{print;next}!(NR%2){a=$0; next} {printf "%s %s%s%s", $1,a,FS,ORS}" FS=";" file ')
```

Notice how everything inside the `'` quotes is green (different from yours).

Comment: Yes I understood your point. I tried this .. but this also showing syntax error

Comment: If the syntax error is being thrown by `awk`, that means the `awk` command itself is broken - which likely it is, because I just ran the above code on my machine and received a `awk: syntax error at source line 1`. Not a Python issue in this case.